# Reordering the column name in crosstab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, crosstab

On a crosstab, i'm looking to reorder the columns listed on the table from "Decreased" "Increased" "Remained" to "Increased" "Remained" "Decreased". Here's an image explaining the exact required change.

[Existing order of columns with required change]

[image: 1]

I'm also looking to do this for an accompanying chart.

Thank you in advance! Josh

Comment: Can you provide code that generates underlying data frame or a ling to the data itself?

Comment: Thanks Marcello. Pierre's answer below appears to have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply select the columns in the order you want. E.g.:

```py
z = pd.crosstab(...)
z[['Increased', 'Remained', 'Decreased']]
```

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you! Exactly as you instructed, I simply added [['Increased', 'Remained', 'Decreased']] to the end of the code

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that `pandas` is sorting this in alphabetical order. There is no hint in the docs how one could rearrange this.

So i would simply rename it like `0_Increased`, `1_Remained`, `2_Decreased`. Maybe this is working for you?

Comment: That you Michael. This looks like a good work around, however Pierre's solution appears to have worked.